# Unable to locate the element after clicking on toggle button

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the assignment for toggle button on the below link :

http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/accordion.php

where the icons will go on and off based on the toggle button.

The HTML code snippet for the buttons are :

```
<h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-corner-all" role="tab" id="ui-id-1" aria-controls="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-e"></span>Section 1</h3>
```

I have switched to the frame already and trying to check the element using :

```
chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-id-1\"]/span")).isEnabled()
```

however after clicking on toggel buttons the icon gets disappeared and the element is not visible at all. Hence I am getting error for the above line. Is there any way to check the icons are there or not?

Comment: you can try isDisplayed method.

Comment: No, Since Element is not visible in html code, it is not able to find the given xpath and hence no method will work for this xpath. It is giving : Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ui-id-1"]/span"}
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.167)

Comment: use the find driver.findelements(<your xapth>).size() method. it will return the count of elements if existed. if the count is greater than 0 then element is preset else element is not present. try this it will definitely work.

Comment: Thanks @Auro, but Let me explain with code. code section is `code`<h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-corner-all" role="tab" id="ui-id-1" aria-controls="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-e"></span>Section 1</h3>`code` and after clicking on toggle button it becomes like `code`<h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" id="ui-id-1" aria-controls="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">Section 1</h3>`code`

Comment: and hence element won't be visible at all. We need to find some other solution instead of finding the web element. can you suggest something with respect to this.

Comment: if you observe the code shared by you, the span element inside of <h3> gets disappeared after you click on toggle button. so use below code. It should work. 
int spanCount=driver.findelements(By.xapth(<your span element xpath>)).size;
if (spanCount>0)
System.out.println("icon Displayed")